# How to place a small square box across every td element having text in css?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working on a table in html in which I want to place a square box across every td element in css

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["series_title"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["episode_title"]; ?></td>    
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["description"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["series_title_fr"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["episode_title_fr"]; ?></td>    
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["description_fr"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"> <?php echo basename($file, ".mp4"); ?></td>
</tr>
```

The above **html/php code** display the **table/td element** in the following fashion:

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the inline css code above so that I am able to make a small square box (as shown below) across every td element having text in css. At this moment, as shown above in an image it is 
making a big square box

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another element, such as a `span`, to wrap the text that is inside each `td`. Then you can style that element with a `border`. For example:

```
<td><span style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">Test</span></td>
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovb2ytdh/). *Table 1*  shows both the borders of `td` and `span`, while *Table 2* only shows the border of `span`.

Answer (score 1):

Your table tag needs a cellspacing.

```
<table cellspacing="10px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["series_title"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["episode_title"]; ?></td>    
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["description"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["series_title_fr"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["episode_title_fr"]; ?></td>    
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo $program["description_fr"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:8%; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px;"><?php echo basename($file, ".mp4"); ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set id for table and set css:

```
#table-id td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cellpadding and cellspacing table attributes. Please try this..

```
  <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <?php echo $program["series_title"]; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $program["episode_title"]; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $program["description"]; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $program["series_title_fr"]; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $program["episode_title_fr"]; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $program["description_fr"]; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [CSS pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) ?

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
}

tr td {
  min-width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr:after {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  content: 'Box';
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```